# how to develop an desktop application for raspberry pi?

Tags: raspbian, python, gui, cross-compilation

am interested in developing a desktop application for raspberry pi. Am having a little bit of coding experience in c and python. The main thing is I don't understand where to start and how to start. I want to know the procedure for developing an application. any help??

Comment: https://magpi.raspberrypi.org/books/create-guis